# Creating boxplots from two rasters using the Raster package in R, using only a subset of classes from one

Tags: raster, r

In R using the raster package, you can create box plots from two rasters (x and y) like so:

```
boxplot(x,y)
```

where:

x = Raster* object
y = If x is a RasterLayer object, y can be an additional RasterLayer to group the values of x by 'zone'

Which works perfectly when I want to group the values of x by all the classes in my thematic raster y.

But if I only want to group the values in x by a subset of the thematic classes in y, is there a way to do this?  I could replace any values in y outside the values I am interested with NODATA values, but I was hoping there a cleaner, simpler method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the value matching operator %in% works perfectly, to replace raster values I don't want (e.g., 4, 7, 10) with NA, and then I can call the boxplot method again.

```
y[y%in%c(4,7,10)] <- NA
```

Comment: you can also use thee `subs` or `reclassify` function